# Increasing icon size mucks up bootstrap layout on large screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I'm making a panel with bootstrap and have run into an issue

#### This is the panel now ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/vbfue61f/3/)):

[image]

Everything is positioned correctly but the icons are a bit small so  I added the following css rule to the icon element:

```
.t-22{
    font-size:22px;
}
```

However, after doing this my layout gets shifted and the last input group gets pulled to the right like this:

#### The panel affter the css ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/vbfue61f/4/))

[image]

**Why does my last element get pulled to the right when I make the icons bigger, even though there seems to be plenty of room for the bigger icon?**

**How can I make the icons 22px in size without messing up the layout?**

Comment: The element didnt  get pulled on my local server.

Comment: @LuckyChingi what browser are you using? Im using chrome and firefox on a mac

Comment: FF 41.0.2 & Chrome 46.0.2490.80

Comment: @LuckyChingi do you have the screen stretched out so that only one element is on the bottom row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the line-height for the icon, it's at `line-height: 31.4286px;` and your text is `line-height: 20px;`

See example Snippet.

```css
.no-wrap-labels label {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
.t-22 {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="so-cat-top-bar"></div>
    <div class="container  ">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><span class="phone-only">Title</span>

                <div class="panel-icons"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="min-height:400px;">
                <div class="panel-options"></div>
                <!-- /panel-options-->
                <div class="tab-content no-wrap-labels" id="category-tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="client">
                        <fieldset class="scheduler-border m-t-15">
                            <legend class="scheduler-border ">Start Time <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Clone this input group" class="preventDefault clone-icon"><i class="icon ion-social-buffer-outline t-22"></i></a>

                            </legend>
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 input-container">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-5 ">
                                                <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Account Number <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Clone this input group" class="preventDefault clone-icon m-l-5">
                                                        <i class="icon ion-social-buffer-outline t-22"></i>
                                                    </a>

                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8  col-lg-7">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" value="4458-465-55811">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 input-container">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-5 ">
                                                <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label"> <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Clone this input group" class="preventDefault clone-icon m-r-5">
                                                        <i class="icon ion-social-buffer-outline t-22"></i>
                                                    </a>Account Number</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8  col-lg-7">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" value="4458-465-55811">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 input-container">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-5 ">
                                                <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Account Number</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8  col-lg-7">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" value="4458-465-55811">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 input-container">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-5 ">
                                                <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Account Number <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Clone this input group" class="preventDefault clone-icon m-l-5">
                                                        <i class="icon ion-social-buffer-outline t-22"></i>
                                                    </a>

                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8  col-lg-7">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" value="4458-465-55811">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </form>
                        </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Last</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default">Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>

                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /tab content-->
            </div>
            <!-- /panel-body-->
        </div>
        <!-- /panel-default -->
    </div>
```

Comment: You're amazing! This has been driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here's my screenshot]

I have a wide screen and this is how it looks. Even if I lower the viewport, it still shows the elements correctly.

Comment: Wow, thats weird. Thanks, Ill check it when I get to work, maybe its just happening on Macs, strange